# Add collision to imported blender scene in babylon js

Tags: javascript, blender

So I created a simple plane and cube scene in blender and exported it as an .obj file. Then I imported the scene in babylon, added the camera to move around etc. The problem is that there seem to be no way I can add collision to the plane I created. If I move I fall right through it. Is there a good example how to add collision to the imported mesh?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/wiki/09-Cameras-and-mesh-collisions

Comment: I tried collisionsEnabled. Doesn't work on imported mesh

Comment: I'm clearly not an expert in Babylon, but I found this : http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/9269-collision-between-imported-meshes-and-camera/ maybe it will help. It talks about the needs to convert the .ong into a .babylon

Comment: These scene importer appears to group all the imported objects together. Then you have to find the mesh inside it. Then attach the collision. Not sure this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize that this is very late to answer you, but I had the same problem with having my camera ellipsoid colliding with my imported blender mesh. I exported the blender object via babylon as a .babylon file. Below is the code I used to enable collisions with the mesh, instantly enabling me to collide whatever meshes with it, of course as long as those meshes also have collisions enabled.

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "", "project_map.babylon", scene, function 
(importedMeshes) { 
  for (i in importedMeshes) {
    importedMeshes[i].checkCollisions = true;
    console.log(i);
  }
});
```

The console.log(i) is to let me know how many meshes are in the imported meshes object passed into the anonymous function of the ImportMesh function. I hope this helps you despite how long it's been since this was posted.